# Unweighted svytable

Tags: r, survey

I am using the `survey` package in R. I am working with survey data and using the `svydesign()` and `update()` functions to manipulate the dataset (create new variables, etc).

Here is how I am getting the weighted crosstabs:

```
## Build svytable
Drinks_Sex <- svytable(~ Sex + Drinks, design=x)
## Cell Totals
round(addmargins(Drinks_Sex),0)

##         Drinks
## Sex          0     1   Sum
##   Female  6501   213  6714
##   Male    5254   157  5411
##   Sum    11755   370 12125
```

Is there a way for me to get the **unweighted** crosstabs using the `survey` package? I know how to get the unweighted crosstabs using base R on the original dataset, but the problem is that doing so would not allow me to analyze any variables using `update()`.

Alternately: is there any way for me to propagate the work I've done using `update()` into the original dataset (in csv format) so I can work it using base R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update` is the same function as `transform`.  if you want to just replace-all your `update` functions with `transform` functions and at the same time replace your `survey.design` with a `data.frame` then it will work.

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)


# variables in the data.frame object inside the design are here: dclus1$variables
# so
head( dclus1$variables )
# is the same as
head( apiclus1 )

# make whatever new variable
dclus1 <- update( dclus1 , new_col = target * 3 )
# equivalent to
# apiclus1 <- transform( apiclus1 , new_col = target * 3 )
# so long as you are working with a data.frame object instead of a survey.design

# just access the `variables` attribute of the survey.design object
# as if it were a data.frame object.  note: this will not work on some very complicated designs (possibly will not work on database-backed or multiply-imputed or calibrated designs)

# single unweighted table
table( dclus1$variables[ , 'new_col' ] )

# crosstabs
table( dclus1$variables[ , c( 'awards' , 'new_col' ) ] )
```

Comment: Special thanks for the bit of code showing how to use $variables. I am now much less mystified by how svydesign works!!

By the way, I am a big fan of http://www.asdfree.com. Maybe I missed this part of the website, but given that you focus on national datasets, a tutorial such as "A practical introduction to using the `survey` package" might be extremely helpful! Just a thought, in case you find yourself with some free time. You can get _some_ of it from reading your sample code, but something more generic, and not dataset-specific, would be lovely.

Comment: thanks @TammyPham, you are welcome to contribute a vignette to asdfree. i learned what i know from places like `?svymean` and the `survey` package website.  note that typing `??update` will show you `?survey:::update.survey.design` which notes `There is now a base-R function transform for adding new variables to a data frame, so I have added transform as a synonym for update for survey objects.` which is where this sort of documentation belongs - and answers your question about a synonym for `update`. i think it's mostly just a matter of getting used to knowing where to look :) keep in touch